# Is there any way to monitor the progress of a download using a WebClient object in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, webclient

I'm downloading a file using a simple line like this:

```
$webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.DownloadFile("https://www.example.com/file", "C:/Local/Path/file")
```

The problem is that I want to display a message to the user while this is downloading using a pop up window, or using a progress bar in the shell. Is it possible to make a pop up box that disappears when the download completes, or a progress bar that monitors the progress of the download?

Comment: If you can upgrade to v3, you can use the built in command `Invoke-WebRequest https://www.site.com/file -OutFile C:/Local/Path/file` and it will display progress automatically.

Answer (score 24):

### To display a progress bar for downloading files check out Jason Niver's Blog post:

[Downloading files from the internet in Power Shell (with progress)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jasonn/downloading-files-from-the-internet-in-powershell-with-progress)

Basically you can create a function that still uses the web client functionality but includes a way to capture the status. You can then display the status to the user using the
Write-Progress Power shell functionality.

```
function DownloadFile($url, $targetFile)

{

   $uri = New-Object "System.Uri" "$url"

   $request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($uri)

   $request.set_Timeout(15000) #15 second timeout

   $response = $request.GetResponse()

   $totalLength = [System.Math]::Floor($response.get_ContentLength()/1024)

   $responseStream = $response.GetResponseStream()

   $targetStream = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileStream -ArgumentList $targetFile, Create

   $buffer = new-object byte[] 10KB

   $count = $responseStream.Read($buffer,0,$buffer.length)

   $downloadedBytes = $count

   while ($count -gt 0)

   {

       $targetStream.Write($buffer, 0, $count)

       $count = $responseStream.Read($buffer,0,$buffer.length)

       $downloadedBytes = $downloadedBytes + $count

       Write-Progress -activity "Downloading file '$($url.split('/') | Select -Last 1)'" -status "Downloaded ($([System.Math]::Floor($downloadedBytes/1024))K of $($totalLength)K): " -PercentComplete ((([System.Math]::Floor($downloadedBytes/1024)) / $totalLength)  * 100)

   }

   Write-Progress -activity "Finished downloading file '$($url.split('/') | Select -Last 1)'"

   $targetStream.Flush()

   $targetStream.Close()

   $targetStream.Dispose()

   $responseStream.Dispose()

}
```

---

Then you would just call the function:

```
downloadFile "http://example.com/largefile.zip" "c:\temp\largefile.zip"
```

---

Also, here are some other Write-Progress examples from docs.microsoft for powrshell 7.

**[Write-Progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-7)**

Comment: I know about `write-progress`; however, I don't think there is any way to increment a counter like that to show the progress of the download.

Comment: This function is much slower than just invoking the download directly.  But if you change the buffer size to 1000KB it makes a HUGE difference.  With the buffer at 10KB, a 300MB file took 392 seconds to download.  At 1000KB, it only took 43 seconds.  The ideal size may vary depending on file size and connection speed, but 10KB is probably to small for most downloads.

Comment: Your Write-Progress link is no longer valid

Comment: @Gwasshoppa thanks! Updated to Microsoft link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-7

Comment: Jason Niver blog link broken

Comment: @codeulike Updated original blog post too Microsoft archive original post link. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

In V2 you could just use the BitsTransfer module e.g.:

```
Import-Module BitsTransfer
Start-BitsTransfer https://www.example.com/file C:/Local/Path/file
```

Comment: `$urls | % { $name = ([uri]$_).Segments[-1]; Start-BitsTransfer $_ -DisplayName $name }`

Comment: Keep in mind that BITS only uses idle network bandwidth.

Comment: Note this does *not* work if you want to use your script in a scheduled task.

Comment: Why will this not work if run in a scheduled task?  If you are sure, have you found way to check?  Code that will run using a bitstransfer if run by hand, but uses another method if run via a scheduled task?

Answer (score 3):

While I worked on rewrite some installation script, I came across this problem. None of these method are ideal. The first method has a performance issue on Windows PowerShell, the second requires up-to-date system and we all knows how it works in real life. ‍♀️

In order to achieve the best possible performance, I combined both method into smart one, made it little bit more general, following PowerShell best practice.

Some benchmarks can be found [here](https://github.com/mrpond/BlockTheSpot/pull/290).

```
function Get-File
{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [System.Uri]
        $Uri,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [System.IO.FileInfo]
        $TargetFile,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Int32]
        $BufferSize = 1,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [ValidateSet('KB, MB')]
        [String]
        $BufferUnit = 'MB',
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [ValidateSet('KB, MB')]
        [Int32]
        $Timeout = 10000
    )

    $useBitTransfer = $null -ne (Get-Module -Name BitsTransfer -ListAvailable) -and ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -le 5)

    if ($useBitTransfer)
    {
        Write-Information -MessageData 'Using a fallback BitTransfer method since you are running Windows PowerShell'
        Start-BitsTransfer -Source $Uri -Destination "$($TargetFile.FullName)"
    }
    else
    {
        $request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($Uri)
        $request.set_Timeout($Timeout) #15 second timeout
        $response = $request.GetResponse()
        $totalLength = [System.Math]::Floor($response.get_ContentLength() / 1024)
        $responseStream = $response.GetResponseStream()
        $targetStream = New-Object -TypeName ([System.IO.FileStream]) -ArgumentList "$($TargetFile.FullName)", Create
        switch ($BufferUnit)
        {
            'KB' { $BufferSize = $BufferSize * 1024 }
            'MB' { $BufferSize = $BufferSize * 1024 * 1024 }
            Default { $BufferSize = 1024 * 1024 }
        }
        Write-Verbose -Message "Buffer size: $BufferSize B ($($BufferSize/("1$BufferUnit")) $BufferUnit)"
        $buffer = New-Object byte[] $BufferSize
        $count = $responseStream.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.length)
        $downloadedBytes = $count
        $downloadedFileName = $Uri -split '/' | Select-Object -Last 1
        while ($count -gt 0)
        {
            $targetStream.Write($buffer, 0, $count)
            $count = $responseStream.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.length)
            $downloadedBytes = $downloadedBytes + $count
            Write-Progress -Activity "Downloading file '$downloadedFileName'" -Status "Downloaded ($([System.Math]::Floor($downloadedBytes/1024))K of $($totalLength)K): " -PercentComplete ((([System.Math]::Floor($downloadedBytes / 1024)) / $totalLength) * 100)
        }

        Write-Progress -Activity "Finished downloading file '$downloadedFileName'"

        $targetStream.Flush()
        $targetStream.Close()
        $targetStream.Dispose()
        $responseStream.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is old question, but I have a elegant solution.

```
$webClient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
$webClient.Credentials = $login
$task = $webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync($uri, $PSScriptRoot + "\" + $asset)

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $webClient -EventName DownloadProgressChanged -SourceIdentifier WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged | Out-Null

Start-Sleep -Seconds 3

while (!($task.IsCompleted)) {
    $EventData = Get-Event -SourceIdentifier WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "SourceEventArgs" -Last 1

    $ReceivedData = ($EventData | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "BytesReceived")
    $TotalToReceive = ($EventData | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "TotalBytesToReceive")
    $TotalPercent = $EventData | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "ProgressPercentage"

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

    Write-Progress -Activity "Downloading File" -Status "Percent Complete: $($TotalPercent)%" -CurrentOperation "Downloaded $(convertFileSize -bytes $ReceivedData) / $(convertFileSize -bytes $TotalToReceive)" -PercentComplete $TotalPercent
}

Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged
$webClient.Dispose()
```

Now, you need one more function for converting file size:

```
function convertFileSize {
    param(
        $bytes
    )

    if ($bytes -lt 1MB) {
        return "$([Math]::Round($bytes / 1KB, 2)) KB"
    }
    elseif ($bytes -lt 1GB) {
        return "$([Math]::Round($bytes / 1MB, 2)) MB"
    }
    elseif ($bytes -lt 1TB) {
        return "$([Math]::Round($bytes / 1GB, 2)) GB"
    }
}
```

I grab the snippet from [Invoke-DownloadFile](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Invoke-DownloadFile/19.5.24). Credits to Tim Small.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use it for better download speed and also for an impressive progress bar.

```
$fullurl='here put URL of the file which one you want to download'
$BASE_DIR= 'specify the path of the file to be stored '
$useBitTransfer = $null -ne (Get-Module -Name BitsTransfer -ListAvailable) -and ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -le 5)
if ($useBitTransfer)
    {
        Write-Information -MessageData 'Using a fallback BitTransfer method since you are running Windows PowerShell'
        Start-BitsTransfer -Source $fullUrl -Destination $BASE_DIR\kubescape.exe
        
    }
    else
    {
       Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $fullUrl -OutFile $BASE_DIR\kubescape.exe
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).